# Read a Google worksheet in Python and loading it in QGIS

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

For a work project I have to read, with Python, a Google Sheets spreadsheet saved in the Drive of the company for which I am doing this project.

The aim is to create a script that, every time it is executed, downloads this file (which is a csv file that contains strings representing geographical coordinates associated with a specific location) and loads it onto the QGIS software, which then transforms that data and transfers them to a map. The aim, in short, is for QGIS to automatically read the data that is loaded into the .csv file by loading it into the map.

My main problem is to access, read and downolad those data and load them in the QGIS software as a pd dataframe with Python.

I tried to finish my project I tried to apply the solution that I found in the official Google's Python quickstart. In particular:

I created a project in Google Cloud, enabled the Google Sheets API and created the relevant key as a json file to be able to access with the relevant credentials;

I later shared the file that I need to download with the email relating to the service account associated with the project;

Finally I took the abovementioned script, I adapted it to my needs and run it in my IDE.

In particular, the adapted code I wrote is the following:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account



SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)


# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = "MY_SPREADSHEET_ID"
service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = (
    sheet.values()
    .get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="MY_RANGE")
    .execute()
)
values = result.get("values", [])

if not values:
    print("No data found.")
    return

for row in values:
    # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
    print(f"{row[0]}, {row[4]}")
```

In doing that I got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1xJO2I8ZCb34N0GB0ahfhx57zES35oGOJjjIGViZvWs8%2Fedit%23gid%3D886092737/values/%21Loan%21a1%3A?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not
> found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.">

So, what I'm asking is: what I'm doing wrong? Are there easier ways to do what I have to do (maybe via web-scraping)?

Thank you very much for helping!